# Can protons be swapped in a chemical reaction?

Tags: acid-base, electrons, elements, protons

Can the protons of two elements be swapped in a chemical reaction?

Comment: Do you mean "two elements" or "two compounds?"

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, no.   This would amount to nuclear fission/fusion, and is generally not considered "chemistry" in any colloquial sense of the term, but rather physics.

In general, chemical reactions consider nuclei to be tightly bound by the [*strong force*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction), and immutable over the course of the reaction.

Disclaimer: there is an ill-defined border between physics and chemistry, and so one could argue that I am wrong about this.  Indeed, *alchemists* had/have been trying to e.g. convert lead to gold for centuries, and this is related to the reaction that you propose.

Comment: umm... proton = hydrogen cation. You don't need fusion to exchange protons.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, and do you normally see hydrogen cations diving into other nuclei?

Comment: The question isn't speaking about nuclei

Comment: As I've mentioned a few times, there is actually "nuclear chemistry," but I agree that outside of bombarding nuclei with protons or alpha particles, this isn't a typical reaction.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Thanks for pointing this out.  This was the origin of my rather guarded language.  long time no talk.  hope all is well :-)